# How to read $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation

Is it correct to say 'dee squared y over dee x squared'?

I am just trying to make sure because I have to teach this to someone.

I learnt that $f''(x)$ is pronounced 'f double prime of x' but I couldn't find how to pronounce Leibniz notation. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is any "official" way to read this symbol. I would just call it the *second derivative*.

Comment: It's the second derivative indeed

Comment: The way you pronounce it is fine. That's what I say.

Comment: I think people often leave out the word "over"

Comment: I usually pronounce it as "dee two $y$ dee $x$ squared". And for $\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}$ I pronounce it "dee three $y$ dee $x$ cubed", but if $k\geq 4$ then I pronounce $\frac{d^ky}{dx^k}$ as "dee $k$ $y$ dee $x$ $k$", where of course people will understand that I mean the $k$ appears in the "exponent" (especially if you say things at the "correct" speed).

Comment: You can also say "$f$ dashed dashed" for $f''$.

Comment: I always say "second derivative" but in my heart I say "dee two y, dee x squared". Have you checked Khan Academy?

Comment: I use the normal way just like you would do with $a^2b/cd^2$ (a-square b by c d-square) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three ways of reading $\dfrac {d^2 y}{dx^2}$...

1. "dee squared y over dee x squared" (your way)
2. "dee two y over dee x two" (informal)
3. The second derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$ (formal)

Comment: Did you mean the second derivative of $\color{red}y\,?$

Comment: Saying “squared” between “dee” and “ex” resolves the issue addressed with the asterisk

Comment: Your (1) and (2) are missing a word like "over" or "by" corresponding to the horizontal bar in the fraction.

Comment: @RobArthan:  isn't that word commonly elided?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: not by me or anyone I have paid attention to (I would always say "by"). However, I don't always pay attention, so I shouldn't have been so dogmatic about this.

Comment: I've corrected my post.  It should have been the second derivative of $y$.

Comment: "dee two y over dee x two" is the best! much more natural.

Answer (score 4):

Formally, you should say : *second order derivative of y w.r.t. x*

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you read it either

- dee two y by dee x squared

or

- dee two y over dee x squared

(either is fine)

Answer (score 2):

You could read as: "dee two y over dee x two"

Comment: No! $R2D2 \neq R^2D^2$ (put $R =D =1$ to see why not). $\ddot{\smile}$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we read it this way. But it is actually the second derivative of the function $y$ which is a function of $x$.